# Making a list of lists in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I'm writing a functor `find/3` in Prolog that should return a list of paths from one destination to another as given by a database of facts. A fact in this database takes the form

```
flight(Carrier,ID,Start,Destination,Hours,Cost).
```

These are meant to simulate a database of flights. Each `flight/6` has a unique `ID`. I'm only working with 3 facts for now:

```
flight('FL', 1, 'TYO', 'PAR', 2, 1800).
flight('WN', 4, 'PAR', 'OSA', 16, 100).
flight('FL', 2, 'TYO', 'OSA', 13, 500).
```

I have a functor `findPaths/4` that returns a list of all `ID`'s to get from one location to another. The following is an example of calling the functor:

```
| ?- findPaths('TYO','OSA',Path,['TYO']).
Path = [2] ? ;
Path = [1,4] ? ;
no
```

So it finds the path that is just `ID`: 2 and the one that is composed of flights `ID`: 1 and `ID`: 4.

I would like my functor `find/3` to return a list of every path that `findPaths/4` finds, but I am quite at a loss of how to do that.

At the moment, this is how I define `find/3`:

```
find(Start,Destination,Paths) :-
    findPaths(Start,Destination,Path,[Start]),
    memberchk(Path,Paths).
```

And here is an example of calling it:

```
| ?- find('TYO','OSA',List).             
List = [[2]|_] ? ;
List = [[1,4]|_] ? ;
no
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. I expect `memberchk/2` to make its first argument a member of its second argument, but I believe I am erroneously thinking about this as if it were an imperative language. I don't know how to correct my reasoning and my functor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`findall/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=findall/3).

```
findall(Path, findPaths('TYO', 'OSA', Path, ['TYO']), ListOfPathLists).
```